# CPU is better for monero mining than GPU?

Tags: mining, cpu-mining, gpu-mining

One of the most mentioned features of Monero mining, is that it's CPU based, I think that it means that nos even having a GPU will improve mining.

I beleive it's like ASICs in ethereum mining, they aren't not allowed, but mining ethereum with an ASIC wont improve mining further than a GPU capacity.

So I asume that for monero mining it would be the same case? You can mine with GPU but it doesn't improves substancially vs a normal CPU?